# How would I authenticate from an Active Directory on a windows server 2016 and .net .core 2.2?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to net framework and Windows stuff. I can't find something clear about this. Do you know a could tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is what you are looking for, but hopefully it is.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#server-side-configuration-with-the-iis-manager